# What does this system.threading._threadpoolwaitcallback.performwaitcallback() and othre methods do?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, clr, appdomain, callstack

I am debugging a .net mvc3 application. Then I opened a output window called : call stack ,than I saw many things....I googled and 'msdned' ,and got no answer. Can someong please tell me what do the following methods do ? Thank you so much! you don't need to tell me every methods listed ,but some of the 'important' ones you think.

*ps: my background knowledge: I read the book "CLR via C#" once ,not fully understand it yet .I know a little about memory manage ,GC,APP domain etc.Just the basic ,you know :)*

**EDIT 1** the following is pasted from the stack ,so ,you may please explain them from the bottom to top ,that's more strait forward :)

**EDIT 2** I know it's a 'big' question ,you may just tell me  which blog ,webpage or book etc I should read to get more understanding :) thank you :)

```
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.RedirectToAction(string actionName, string controllerName, object routeValues) 
System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase controller, object[] parameters)
System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext,     System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,object> parameters)
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,object> parameters) 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters.AnonymousMethod__12() 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(System.Web.Mvc.IActionFilter filter, System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutingContext preContext, System.Func<System.Web.Mvc.ActionExecutedContext> continuation) 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters.AnonymousMethod__14() 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Collections.Generic.IList<System.Web.Mvc.IActionFilter> filters, System.Web.Mvc.ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string,object> parameters) 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName) 
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext) 
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.System.Web.Mvc.IController.Execute(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext) 
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest.AnonymousMethod__5() 
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.MakeVoidDelegate.AnonymousMethod__0()
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.BeginSynchronous<System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncVoid>.AnonymousMethod__7(System.IAsyncResult _) 
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult<System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncVoid>.End()
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest.AnonymousMethod__d() 
System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.GetCallInAppTrustThunk.AnonymousMethod__0(System.Action f)
System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(System.Action action) 
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) 
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(System.IAsyncResult result) 
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() 
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep step, ref bool completedSynchronously) +
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.ApplicationStepManager.ResumeSteps(System.Exception error) System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpApplication.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpContext context, System.AsyncCallback cb, object extraData) +
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest wr) +
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNoDemand(System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest wr) + 
System.Web.dll!System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequest(System.Web.HttpWorkerRequest wr) + 
WebDev.WebHost40.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Request.Process() + 0x17b WebDev.WebHost40.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Host.ProcessRequest(Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Connection conn) +
WebDev.WebHost40.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Server.OnSocketAccept(object acceptedSocket) +  
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(object state) +    
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool ignoreSyncCtx) +   
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem() + 
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch() + 
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback() + 0x2d
```

Comment: I am seeing the same problem signature.  But I am seeing it in the context of a simple .ashx page which is using System.Data.SqlClient to call out to an sql server.
Here's what my stack looks like, according to visual studio:

`Microsoft.VisualStudio.WebHost.Server.OnSocketAccept()
System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context()
System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run()
System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()`

Comment: Further note: in my case, the problem was a simple (and incorrect) recursive call in my managed code.  The above stack trace was "valid" -- just not useful in isolating the problem. -- I suspect that your problem is probably similar.  When a stack overflow occurs, it may not be the case that the exception occurs in the appdomain which you control, that needs to be fixed.